# Same cookies on two different devices

Tags: cookies, google-account, mobile-devices

is it possible to have the same cookies on two different devices both connected to the same google account? do not treat me badly is a customer's request. I tried almost everything, including javascript functions and various things in php but nothing.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using cookies u should use session?

Comment: I think the same way, unfortunately the customer wants the cookie id to be identical if I log in from a PC or mobile phone with the same google account @IsaacLem

Comment: Perhaps instead of focusing on sticking to cookies, u may want to find out what your objective that your customers trying to achieve instead, and move on from there